# HDD makes a noise occasionally, and I get this error

Tags: linux, hard-drive, smart

I've tried changing the SATA Cables, and SATA Power Cables from the working HDD's to this HDD but I still get this error, and the other drives work fine. I've tried adding the `libata.force=noncq` kernel parameter but it didn't help. I've tried running long smartctl test but it gets interrupted with this error. The hard drive still works fine even with the error though.

Can anybody tell me if this is a bad drive or something else?

`journalctl -f -p 1..3` or `sudo dmesg --level err --follow`

```
Feb 21 14:18:08 entonkde kernel: ata6.00: exception Emask 0x50 SAct 0x0 SErr 0xb0802 action 0xe frozen
Feb 21 14:18:08 entonkde kernel: ata6.00: irq_stat 0x00400000, PHY RDY changed
Feb 21 14:18:08 entonkde kernel: ata6: SError: { RecovComm HostInt PHYRdyChg PHYInt 10B8B }
Feb 21 14:18:08 entonkde kernel: ata6.00: failed command: READ DMA EXT
Feb 21 14:18:08 entonkde kernel: ata6.00: cmd 25/00:20:40:98:44/00:01:89:00:00/e0 tag 10 dma 147456 in
                                          res 50/00:00:3f:98:44/00:00:89:00:00/e0 Emask 0x50 (ATA bus error)
Feb 21 14:18:08 entonkde kernel: ata6.00: status: { DRDY }
Feb 21 14:18:24 entonkde kernel: ata6.00: revalidation failed (errno=-5)
Feb 21 14:18:24 entonkde kernel: blk_update_request: I/O error, dev sdd, sector 2302974016 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x80000 phys_seg 26 prio class 0
```

`smartctl -x /dev/sdd`.

```
smartctl 7.4 2023-08-01 r5530 [x86_64-linux-5.15.146-1-MANJARO] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-23, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate BarraCuda 3.5 (CMR)
Device Model:     ST10000DM0004-1ZC101
Serial Number:    ZA2BHBMR
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0b6938dd7
Firmware Version: DN01
User Capacity:    10,000,831,348,736 bytes [10.0 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    7200 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database 7.3/5528
ATA Version is:   ACS-3 T13/2161-D revision 5
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Wed Feb 21 15:14:02 2024 IST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled
AAM feature is:   Unavailable
APM feature is:   Unavailable
Rd look-ahead is: Enabled
Write cache is:   Enabled
DSN feature is:   Unavailable
ATA Security is:  Disabled, NOT FROZEN [SEC1]
Wt Cache Reorder: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline
data collection:        (  567) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 861) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x50bd) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAGS    VALUE WORST THRESH FAIL RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     POSR--   077   064   044    -    45827004
  3 Spin_Up_Time            PO----   094   089   000    -    0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        -O--CK   094   094   020    -    6296
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   PO--CK   100   100   010    -    0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         POSR--   094   060   045    -    2571384965
  9 Power_On_Hours          -O--CK   070   070   000    -    27150 (61 71 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        PO--C-   100   100   097    -    0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       -O--CK   094   094   020    -    6295
184 End-to-End_Error        -O--CK   100   100   099    -    0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0
188 Command_Timeout         -O--CK   100   100   000    -    0 0 0
189 High_Fly_Writes         -O-RCK   001   001   000    -    235
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel -O---K   064   047   040    -    36 (Min/Max 36/36)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      -O--CK   095   095   000    -    10152
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count -O--CK   097   097   000    -    6258
193 Load_Cycle_Count        -O--CK   024   024   000    -    153690
194 Temperature_Celsius     -O---K   036   053   000    -    36 (0 23 0 0 0)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  -O-RC-   005   001   000    -    45827004
197 Current_Pending_Sector  -O--C-   100   100   000    -    0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   ----C-   100   100   000    -    0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    -OSRCK   200   200   000    -    0
200 Pressure_Limit          PO---K   100   100   001    -    0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       ------   100   253   000    -    23672h+13m+54.776s
241 Total_LBAs_Written      ------   100   253   000    -    67755413145
242 Total_LBAs_Read         ------   100   253   000    -    16415460016
                            ||||||_ K auto-keep
                            |||||__ C event count
                            ||||___ R error rate
                            |||____ S speed/performance
                            ||_____ O updated online
                            |______ P prefailure warning

General Purpose Log Directory Version 1
SMART           Log Directory Version 1 [multi-sector log support]
Address    Access  R/W   Size  Description
0x00       GPL,SL  R/O      1  Log Directory
0x01           SL  R/O      1  Summary SMART error log
0x02           SL  R/O      5  Comprehensive SMART error log
0x03       GPL     R/O      5  Ext. Comprehensive SMART error log
0x04       GPL     R/O    256  Device Statistics log
0x04       SL      R/O      8  Device Statistics log
0x06           SL  R/O      1  SMART self-test log
0x07       GPL     R/O      1  Extended self-test log
0x08       GPL     R/O      2  Power Conditions log
0x09           SL  R/W      1  Selective self-test log
0x0c       GPL     R/O   2048  Pending Defects log
0x10       GPL     R/O      1  NCQ Command Error log
0x11       GPL     R/O      1  SATA Phy Event Counters log
0x13       GPL     R/O      1  SATA NCQ Send and Receive log
0x15       GPL     R/W      1  Rebuild Assist log
0x21       GPL     R/O      1  Write stream error log
0x22       GPL     R/O      1  Read stream error log
0x24       GPL     R/O    768  Current Device Internal Status Data log
0x30       GPL,SL  R/O      9  IDENTIFY DEVICE data log
0x80-0x9f  GPL,SL  R/W     16  Host vendor specific log
0xa1       GPL,SL  VS      24  Device vendor specific log
0xa2       GPL     VS   16320  Device vendor specific log
0xa6       GPL     VS     192  Device vendor specific log
0xa8-0xa9  GPL,SL  VS     136  Device vendor specific log
0xab       GPL     VS       1  Device vendor specific log
0xad       GPL     VS      16  Device vendor specific log
0xb0       GPL     VS   17208  Device vendor specific log
0xbe-0xbf  GPL     VS   65535  Device vendor specific log
0xc1       GPL,SL  VS      16  Device vendor specific log
0xc3       GPL,SL  VS       8  Device vendor specific log
0xc9       GPL,SL  VS       8  Device vendor specific log
0xca       GPL,SL  VS      16  Device vendor specific log
0xd1       GPL     VS     304  Device vendor specific log
0xd2       GPL     VS   10000  Device vendor specific log
0xd4       GPL     VS    2048  Device vendor specific log
0xe0       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Command/Status
0xe1       GPL,SL  R/W      1  SCT Data Transfer

SMART Extended Comprehensive Error Log Version: 1 (5 sectors)
No Errors Logged

SMART Extended Self-test Log Version: 1 (1 sectors)
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      00%     27136         -
# 2  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      00%     27103         -
# 3  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      00%     27102         -
# 4  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      00%     27070         -
# 5  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      00%     27037         -
# 6  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%     27032         -
# 7  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     27006         -
# 8  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     26993         -
# 9  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     26968         -
#10  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     26945         -
#11  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     26944         -
#12  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      00%     26921         -
#13  Extended offline    Interrupted (host reset)      00%     26919         -
#14  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     26896         -
#15  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     26896         -
#16  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     26872         -
#17  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     26848         -
#18  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     26848         -
#19  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     26824         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.

SCT Status Version:                  3
SCT Version (vendor specific):       522 (0x020a)
Device State:                        Active (0)
Current Temperature:                    36 Celsius
Power Cycle Min/Max Temperature:     36/36 Celsius
Lifetime    Min/Max Temperature:     21/53 Celsius
Under/Over Temperature Limit Count:   0/1

SCT Temperature History Version:     2
Temperature Sampling Period:         3 minutes
Temperature Logging Interval:        59 minutes
Min/Max recommended Temperature:      0/ 0 Celsius
Min/Max Temperature Limit:            0/ 0 Celsius
Temperature History Size (Index):    128 (26)

Index    Estimated Time   Temperature Celsius
  27    2024-02-16 09:48     ?  -
  28    2024-02-16 10:47    36  *****************
  29    2024-02-16 11:46     ?  -
  30    2024-02-16 12:45    36  *****************
  31    2024-02-16 13:44     ?  -
  32    2024-02-16 14:43    36  *****************
  33    2024-02-16 15:42     ?  -
  34    2024-02-16 16:41    36  *****************
  35    2024-02-16 17:40     ?  -
  36    2024-02-16 18:39    36  *****************
  37    2024-02-16 19:38     ?  -
  38    2024-02-16 20:37    36  *****************
  39    2024-02-16 21:36     ?  -
  40    2024-02-16 22:35    36  *****************
  41    2024-02-16 23:34     ?  -
  42    2024-02-17 00:33    36  *****************
  43    2024-02-17 01:32     ?  -
  44    2024-02-17 02:31    36  *****************
  45    2024-02-17 03:30     ?  -
  46    2024-02-17 04:29    36  *****************
  47    2024-02-17 05:28     ?  -
  48    2024-02-17 06:27    36  *****************
  49    2024-02-17 07:26     ?  -
  50    2024-02-17 08:25    36  *****************
  51    2024-02-17 09:24     ?  -
  52    2024-02-17 10:23    36  *****************
  53    2024-02-17 11:22     ?  -
  54    2024-02-17 12:21    35  ****************
  55    2024-02-17 13:20     ?  -
  56    2024-02-17 14:19    35  ****************
  57    2024-02-17 15:18     ?  -
  58    2024-02-17 16:17    35  ****************
  59    2024-02-17 17:16     ?  -
  60    2024-02-17 18:15    35  ****************
  61    2024-02-17 19:14     ?  -
  62    2024-02-17 20:13    35  ****************
  63    2024-02-17 21:12     ?  -
  64    2024-02-17 22:11    35  ****************
  65    2024-02-17 23:10     ?  -
  66    2024-02-18 00:09    35  ****************
  67    2024-02-18 01:08     ?  -
  68    2024-02-18 02:07    35  ****************
  69    2024-02-18 03:06     ?  -
  70    2024-02-18 04:05    35  ****************
  71    2024-02-18 05:04     ?  -
  72    2024-02-18 06:03    35  ****************
  73    2024-02-18 07:02     ?  -
  74    2024-02-18 08:01    35  ****************
  75    2024-02-18 09:00     ?  -
  76    2024-02-18 09:59    35  ****************
  77    2024-02-18 10:58     ?  -
  78    2024-02-18 11:57    35  ****************
  79    2024-02-18 12:56     ?  -
  80    2024-02-18 13:55    35  ****************
  81    2024-02-18 14:54     ?  -
  82    2024-02-18 15:53    35  ****************
  83    2024-02-18 16:52     ?  -
  84    2024-02-18 17:51    35  ****************
  85    2024-02-18 18:50     ?  -
  86    2024-02-18 19:49    35  ****************
  87    2024-02-18 20:48     ?  -
  88    2024-02-18 21:47    35  ****************
  89    2024-02-18 22:46     ?  -
  90    2024-02-18 23:45    35  ****************
  91    2024-02-19 00:44     ?  -
  92    2024-02-19 01:43    35  ****************
  93    2024-02-19 02:42     ?  -
  94    2024-02-19 03:41    27  ********
  95    2024-02-19 04:40     ?  -
  96    2024-02-19 05:39    27  ********
  97    2024-02-19 06:38     ?  -
  98    2024-02-19 07:37    28  *********
  99    2024-02-19 08:36     ?  -
 100    2024-02-19 09:35    28  *********
 101    2024-02-19 10:34    36  *****************
 102    2024-02-19 11:33     ?  -
 103    2024-02-19 12:32    36  *****************
 104    2024-02-19 13:31     ?  -
 105    2024-02-19 14:30    35  ****************
 106    2024-02-19 15:29    39  ********************
 107    2024-02-19 16:28    37  ******************
 108    2024-02-19 17:27    38  *******************
 109    2024-02-19 18:26    39  ********************
 110    2024-02-19 19:25    39  ********************
 111    2024-02-19 20:24    38  *******************
 ...    ..(  4 skipped).    ..  *******************
 116    2024-02-20 01:19    38  *******************
 117    2024-02-20 02:18    39  ********************
 118    2024-02-20 03:17    37  ******************
 119    2024-02-20 04:16    36  *****************
 120    2024-02-20 05:15    37  ******************
 ...    ..(  3 skipped).    ..  ******************
 124    2024-02-20 09:11    37  ******************
 125    2024-02-20 10:10    38  *******************
 126    2024-02-20 11:09    38  *******************
 127    2024-02-20 12:08    39  ********************
   0    2024-02-20 13:07    39  ********************
   1    2024-02-20 14:06    38  *******************
   2    2024-02-20 15:05    38  *******************
   3    2024-02-20 16:04    39  ********************
 ...    ..(  2 skipped).    ..  ********************
   6    2024-02-20 19:01    39  ********************
   7    2024-02-20 20:00    38  *******************
   8    2024-02-20 20:59    39  ********************
   9    2024-02-20 21:58    39  ********************
  10    2024-02-20 22:57    38  *******************
  11    2024-02-20 23:56     ?  -
  12    2024-02-21 00:55    39  ********************
  13    2024-02-21 01:54    37  ******************
  14    2024-02-21 02:53    36  *****************
  15    2024-02-21 03:52    36  *****************
  16    2024-02-21 04:51    36  *****************
  17    2024-02-21 05:50    35  ****************
 ...    ..(  5 skipped).    ..  ****************
  23    2024-02-21 11:44    35  ****************
  24    2024-02-21 12:43    36  *****************
  25    2024-02-21 13:42     ?  -
  26    2024-02-21 14:41    36  *****************

SCT Error Recovery Control:
           Read:     70 (7.0 seconds)
          Write:     70 (7.0 seconds)

Device Statistics (GP Log 0x04)
Page  Offset Size        Value Flags Description
0x01  =====  =               =  ===  == General Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x01  0x008  4            6295  ---  Lifetime Power-On Resets
0x01  0x010  4           27150  ---  Power-on Hours
0x01  0x018  6     67302990343  ---  Logical Sectors Written
0x01  0x020  6       374489298  ---  Number of Write Commands
0x01  0x028  6     13471007910  ---  Logical Sectors Read
0x01  0x030  6       244594896  ---  Number of Read Commands
0x01  0x038  6               -  ---  Date and Time TimeStamp
0x03  =====  =               =  ===  == Rotating Media Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x03  0x008  4      1140449289  N--  Spindle Motor Power-on Hours
0x03  0x010  4      1140441398  N--  Head Flying Hours
0x03  0x018  4          153690  ---  Head Load Events
0x03  0x020  4               0  ---  Number of Reallocated Logical Sectors
0x03  0x028  4               0  ---  Read Recovery Attempts
0x03  0x030  4               0  ---  Number of Mechanical Start Failures
0x03  0x038  4               0  ---  Number of Realloc. Candidate Logical Sectors
0x03  0x040  4            6258  ---  Number of High Priority Unload Events
0x04  =====  =               =  ===  == General Errors Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x04  0x008  4               0  ---  Number of Reported Uncorrectable Errors
0x04  0x010  4               0  ---  Resets Between Cmd Acceptance and Completion
0x05  =====  =               =  ===  == Temperature Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x05  0x008  1              36  ---  Current Temperature
0x05  0x010  1              36  ---  Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x018  1              39  ---  Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x020  1              53  ---  Highest Temperature
0x05  0x028  1               0  ---  Lowest Temperature
0x05  0x030  1              48  ---  Highest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x038  1              33  ---  Lowest Average Short Term Temperature
0x05  0x040  1              44  ---  Highest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x048  1              37  ---  Lowest Average Long Term Temperature
0x05  0x050  4               0  ---  Time in Over-Temperature
0x05  0x058  1              60  ---  Specified Maximum Operating Temperature
0x05  0x060  4             320  ---  Time in Under-Temperature
0x05  0x068  1               5  ---  Specified Minimum Operating Temperature
0x06  =====  =               =  ===  == Transport Statistics (rev 1) ==
0x06  0x008  4              47  ---  Number of Hardware Resets
0x06  0x010  4              10  ---  Number of ASR Events
0x06  0x018  4               0  ---  Number of Interface CRC Errors
0xff  =====  =               =  ===  == Vendor Specific Statistics (rev 1) ==
0xff  0x008  7               0  ---  Vendor Specific
                                |||_ C monitored condition met
                                ||__ D supports DSN
                                |___ N normalized value

Pending Defects log (GP Log 0x0c)
No Defects Logged

SATA Phy Event Counters (GP Log 0x11)
ID      Size     Value  Description
0x000a  2            2  Device-to-host register FISes sent due to a COMRESET
0x0001  2            0  Command failed due to ICRC error
0x0003  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host data FIS
0x0004  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device data FIS
0x0006  2            0  R_ERR response for device-to-host non-data FIS
0x0007  2            0  R_ERR response for host-to-device non-data FIS

Seagate FARM log (GP Log 0xa6) supported [try: -l farm]
```

Comment: Could be a problem with drive electronics (instead of mechanical parts).

Comment: Yeah, I'd treat the drive as bad.  When you start seeing those kinds of errors the drive is usually on the way out.  That seek error rate would give me pause.

Comment: "seek error rate" - If this is a Seagate this is normal. In case of Seagate above seek error rate translates to: 0 errors in 45,827,004 operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Power Supply was the problem. Everything's working fine after I replaced it.

Comment: You'll want to address the airflow issues in the case, as your drives are getting way too hot at 53C [128.6F] _(that's hot enough to cause a severe burn if touched - for comparison, hot water heaters are usually set to a max of 120F)_ and that will lead to premature failure - under load, ideally no higher than the mid-40s